# If infinitesimal transformations commute why don't the generators of the Lorentz group commute?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, commutator, lie-algebra

If infinitesimal transformations commute as proved e.g. on [this mathworld.wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfinitesimalRotation.html), why are the commutators for the generators of the Lorentz group nonzero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll use ordinary rotations as an example. The same reasoning applies for other Lorentz transformations, too.

Suppose that $G_x$ and $G_y$ generate rotations about the $x$- and $y$-axes, respectively. This means that $\exp(\theta G_x)$ is a rotation through angle $\theta$ about the $x$-axis, and $\exp(\phi G_y)$ is a rotation through angle $\phi$ about the $y$-axis. Those rotations don't commute with each other, so $G_x$ and $G_y$ must not commute with each other, either.

When the linked website (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfinitesimalRotation.html) talks about the "commutativity of infinitesimal transformations," it means that if the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ both have infinitesimal magnitude $\epsilon\ll 1$, then the rotations $\exp(\theta G_x)$ and $\exp(\phi G_y)$ commute with each other *to first order in $\epsilon$*. This is true even though the generators $G_x$ and $G_y$ don't commute with each other, because the terms in the composite rotation $\exp(\theta G_x)\exp(\phi G_y)$ that involve products of $G_x$ and $G_y$ are of order $\epsilon^2\ll\epsilon$, so the non-commutativity of the generators $G_x$ and $G_y$ doesn't affect things at first order in $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Illustrative example:* It is straightforward to prove that the [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) 
   $$ SO(3)~:=~\{ M\in {\rm Mat}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \mid M^tM=\mathbb{1}_{3\times 3}, ~\det(M)=1\} $$ 
   of [3D rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) is generated by the corresponding [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)
   $$ so(3)~:=~\{ m\in {\rm Mat}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \mid m^t=-m\} $$
   of real $3\times 3$ antisymmetric matrices, which clearly do *not* all commute.
2. Concretely notice how the mathworld.wolfram page in eqs. (2)-(5) omits the second-order terms, whose difference reveals the commutator!

Answer (score 0):

While 
\begin{align}
e^{\epsilon A} e^{\epsilon B}&=(1+\epsilon A+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 A^2+\ldots)(1+\epsilon B+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 B^2+\ldots)\tag{1}\, ,\\
&= 1+ \epsilon (A+B)+ \frac{1}{2}
\epsilon^2 (A^2+AB +B^2)+\ldots 
\end{align}
we have 
\begin{align}
e^{\epsilon B} e^{\epsilon A}&=(1+\epsilon B+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 B^2+\ldots)(1+\epsilon A+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 A^2+\ldots)\, ,\tag{2}\\
&= 1+ \epsilon (B+A)+ \frac{1}{2}
\epsilon^2 (A^2+BA +B^2)+\ldots 
\end{align}
so:

1. To order $\epsilon$, the transformations are the same,
2. To order $\epsilon^2$ they are different.

Since the commutator $[A,B]$ involves products like $AB$ and $BA$, one must compare terms in $\epsilon^2$ in (1) and (2) to see that they differ by a commutator.